# Confusion about Transparent Background in CSS

Tags: css

I know the transparency can be attained using value `rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.6)`. I want to know what does `221,221,221,0.6` denotes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`rgba()` color notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) allows you to specify the red, green, blue and alpha values for a color respectively. That means 221 red, 221 green, 221 blue and 0.6 (60%) alpha.

The RGB values have a range of 0 to 255; this is the standard range for the [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) and notation (this is explained in the preceding section for the [`rgb()` notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color)). The higher the value for a color component, the more that color component will be blended into the resulting color.

The alpha value has a range of 0 to 1, with decimal values. It is what determines the opacity (or transparency) of the color. The higher the value, the more opaque the resulting color will be.

Comment: if I use (225,100,100,0.6) ...Does this thickens the red layer??

Answer (score 0):

By component:

- RED
- GREEN
- BLUE
- ALPHA

(rgba is an acronym for these.) Color components can be either absolute values in the range of **[0-255]** or percentages **0%...100%** (which can be converted to absolute values using

**absVal = 255 * pctVal / 100**.) the **Alpha** component can be a float in the **[0..1]** range (0 stands for completely transparent, 1 stands for completely opaque colors.)

Similarly, you can use `hsl` (or `hsla` for alpha) to employ the [HSL color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space).

See [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) to see how you can specify color values in CSS.

Comment: What if we use any other value in place of 221??

Answer (score 0):

as the guys say Red Green Blue Alpha more info on the values:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp
basicaly you use a combination of the 3 colors to make each color you need, the bigger the number the more of that collor is added in the "mix"

Answer (score 0):

Seems, like you are not clear about the concept of color values.

Every color values is represented by 8bit length. That is `11111111` which translates to `256`, but since `0` is the starting digit. The max value in 255.

Whenever defining color, there are `3` major colors, `red`,`green` and `blue`, which is what `rgb` stands for. Since, CSS3 it give us the possibility of transparency, by implementing one more property `alpha` which represent the opacity of the color value. So, the new command become `rgba`

Now,

> r: `255` stands for max red color
>
> g: `255` stands for max green color
>
> b: `255` stands for max green color

When all the color values have maximum values, the resulting color is `white`, which is exactly what happens, when you are spinning a color wheel.

Now, comes the `alpha` part. It is represent in `percentage/100`. So `1` would be completely opaque and `0` would be completely transparent.